# How to open all buffers in the same window and never create new one?

Tags: window, window-splitting

I'm using emacs in terminal via `emacs-nox` and I wish to sort of disable windows functionality at all. I mean I do not want each time to add some buffer to use  `display-buffer-same-window` function, I wish emacs to not create windows never at all, and use only the same one window that was created at startup. How can I do that, maybe I should rewrite `view-buffer-other-window`?

Comment: Nice question....